# MailChimp API, Groups, Segments, and Lists

Tags: mailchimp

I have a few questions about MailChimp and am looking for a "best practices" answer from someone who knows better than I do. I have several hundred subscribers in a specific list on MailChimp. What I want to do is essentially "classify" them into different groups or segments (I don't know which) based on match calculations like (purchased between 1 and 4 weeks ago, 5-10 weeks ago, etc).

We would like to create specific email campaigns and then blast the subscribers based on the math. I am not sure whether I should use "Groups" or "Segments". We are wanting to run a weekly chron job to reclassify everyone. So we would like to first clear (not delete segments or groups or unsubsribe users) the group or segment and then start looping through our user base and do API calls to reclassify them where we need them to be.

Can anyone help me understand this? I have read the KB (http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/groups-and-segments/about-segments-and-groups) but I am still not clear on how I should approach this (groups vs. segments I think).

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you create a group for each "match-calculation", you'll have a group for "purchased between 1 and 4 weeks ago" and one more for "5-10 weeks ago", then, you'll create a segment for each group (List->Manage Subscribers->Create Segment). When creating a campaign you'll be able to select a segment.

> So we would like to first clear (not delete segments or groups or
>   unsubsribe users) the group or segment and then start looping through
>   our user base and do API calls to reclassify them where we need them
>   to be.

You don't have to clear the segment when executing your cron job, you could update your groups for each user (which would update the members in each segment). Here's an example of updating a subscriber.

> ( POST request to
>   https://us8.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/  lists/update-member )

```
{
  "apikey":"Key"
  "id":"listID",
  "email":{
    "email":"email@domain.com"
  },
  "merge_vars":{
    "GROUPINGS":[
      {
        "id":groupingsID,
        "groups":{
          "four_weeks":"four_weeks",
          "ten_weeks":"ten_weeks"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "email_type":"html"
}
```

Above I'm adding the subscriber to two groups (thereby to the two segments).

*Angel*

Comment: I don't found the documentation of lists/update-member in the API v3. Do you have this information? In the new version, how to do the same?

Comment: @angelcervera here the docs for the API v3 
[link](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#edit-patch_lists_list_id_members_subscriber_hash). I do not have the code for v3. I haven't try it.

Comment: In case anyone or @angelcervera runs into this question: [edit-patch_lists_list_id_members_subscriber_hash](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#edit-patch_lists_list_id_members_subscriber_hash)